# Problem with list blocking a latexmk vs autolatex question

Tags: discussion

So, I'd like to know the difference between `latexmk` and `autolatex`. So I do a search, [and look there is a question on it.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41500/autolatex-or-latexmk) Oh, wait, it is closed as a duplicate, well, I'll go to [the question is was closed as a duplicate of.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation) Lets see:

65 upvotes:

> [Latexmk is one possibility, although I've never used it myself.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234/7880)

Well, that doesn't have much information on it, [what about autolatex? It only has 3 upvotes:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76/7880)

> For completeness, I will mention autolatex (project page). I have not used it. It's implemented with a combination of perl scripts and makefiles.
>
> With autolatex you can execute on the command line:
>
> $ autolatex -f mydoc.tex
>
> This generates the makefiles in the current directory and makes the default targets.

So neither answer has any information on what the differences between `autolatex` and `latexmk`, yet I still can't make a new question on it.

[The chat recommended I make a meta question here, and that it would hopefully wind up with improving the list questions answers.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13167852#13167852)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I suggest making the [big-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) more systematic.** My proposal, feel free to add your ideas:

Each answer in that question should treat one automation tool exactly (this seems to be true for all but [Paul Biggar's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1882) answers).

The following information about each tool should be present:

- Name, with link to homepage or manual if applicable
- Link to its tag, if it has a dedicated tag.
- It's basic abilities and basic weaknesses, probably as a list of tools it supports. I suggest: `makeindex`, `makeglossaries`, `biber`, `bibtex`.
- How to invoke it, what basic options/parameters it has (this is simple for tools like `latexmk`, more difficult for tools like `arara` or `make`, suggestions on how to treat this are welcomed)
- Platforms, Licensing (at least in "free"/"non-free", but seeing the list, all seem to be "free")

I hope this makes sense. After all, this is CW, so please bring in your ideas!

Comment: My one problem with this is that it is only in general: I'd like to know the exact differences between the two programs, so while it would work for differences between say the emacs method and a CLI method, it might not cover fine details. I'd say the question isn't a duplicate, so open it, but add a link to the big list for other alternatives.

Comment: @Canageek Well, just add a comment why you think it's not a duplicate, and vote for re-open. You'll see what happens ;)

Comment: As long as it isn't "You get murdered in your sleep" ....

Comment: The question seems to be open again, but it still has the "possible duplicate" message. Does it need to be edited out by hand?

Comment: @StephanLehmke It has now had the title edited to better reflect the question.

Comment: The question has been reopened, but I still think this is an excellent idea.